# Port numbers used by IBM HTTP Server and Websphere v6

Tags: ssl, port, websphere, ihs

I'm trying to understand what port numbers i can use to access my application both through the web server (IBM Http Server) and directly to the app server (IBM Websphere v6.1).

What ports can i use to bypass IHS and hit server directly using HTTP and HTTPS?
What ports can i use to pass through IHS server using HTTP and HTTPS?
What are the default ports and are there other ports i should be aware of?

Is this information stored in a config file or is it dependent on how i configure host aliases?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to see which ports are used by a specific server is under with the administrative console. Visit Servers > Application Servers, then select the particular server and expand its Ports section on the right.

`WC_defaulthost` and `WC_defaulthost_secure` are the direct http and https ports on which the WebContainer is listening.

The Virtual Host to which your application is connected must also have those ports in its alias list. If it doesn't, the application won't respond to direct requests to the ports (even though the WebContainer is listening on them for the IHS plugin). The default hosts WAS creates will have those ports added automatically, but you'll have to add them manually to any new Virtual Hosts you create.